# CSS bootstrap: add icon to h1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i add icon(Bootstrap Glyphicons) in `h1` but `icon` not in text `baseline`. how to fix This?!

[Problem pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P92j4.png)

Code:

```
<h1 ><a><i class="icon-play"></i>TEST TEXT</a></h1>
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 8):

For Bootstrap version 3 use this.

```
<h1>Hi this is heading<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star</h1>
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10/) jsfiddle.

your icon size will change according to size of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Im using Bootstrap v3.2 and I had the same problem.

`<h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> User</h3>`

so I changed the display property of the glyphicon from inline-block to inline.

```
.glyphicon 
{position: relative;
top: 1px;
display: inline;
...
}
```

This is due the An inline element has no line break before or after it, and it tolerates HTML elements next to it but an inline-block element is placed as an inline element (on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

1) changing padding of i.icon-play

2) background-position of i.icon-play

3) vertical-align:center; line-height:12px; of i.icon-play

One of those will work, good luck ;-)