# Add glyphicon to headings

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18567417/4556720) answer I'm trying to add icon to `h3` tag. Here is a result:

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h1>Play it! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play text-primary"/></h1>
```

Also [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agqqft99/) available.

But inside `h3` tag the icon becomes too big. I would prefer something like this:

[image]

How can I make the icon smaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your HTML just add the CSS:

```
h1 span.glyphicon-play{
    font-size: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the font-size of the glyphicon

```
h1 .glyphicon {
font-size:.5em;
```

}

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/agqqft99/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1>Play it! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" style="font-size:15px;"></span></h1>
```

Try This code

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways, one way is to write css for it, as mentioned in the above replies. Another possible way is using `<small>` tag. This would be answer if you don't want to dynamically decrease the font-size in css. Another solution is to give it a new class `btn-sm` especially if this is a button.

http://jsfiddle.net/agqqft99/10/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h1>Play it! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play text-primary"/></h1>
```