# How do I add small text in H1 tag in html?

Tags: html

I am trying to add small text within the H1 tags at the same time adding an icon before the text, but unfortunately it is not working, I have two issue in the same h1 tag in the header class noting that I am building my site using bootstrap framework :

1. Small tag is not working inside h1 tag
2. Glyph icons are not being added using bootstrap inside the same h1
   tag.

Below is the code I am using:

```css
body{
    background: #f4f4f4;
}

.navbar-nav{
    min-height: 33px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}
.navbar .navbar-text {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar .navbar-text a {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}
.navbar .navbar-text a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-text a:focus {
  color: #ffbbbc; 
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:not(.disabled):hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:not(.disabled):focus {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  border-color: #c0392b;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
  color: #ffbbbc;
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-divider {
  border-top-color: #c0392b;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link:focus {
  color: #ffbbbc;
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler {
  border-color: #c0392b;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler:hover,
.navbar .navbar-toggler:focus {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse,
.navbar .navbar-form {
  border-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar .navbar-link {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}

.main-color-bg{
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  border-color: #c0392b;
  color:#ffffff;
}














@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #ffbbbc;
    background-color: #c0392b;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #ffbbbc;
    background-color: #c0392b;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #ffbbbc;
    background-color: #c0392b;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #ffbbbc;
    background-color: #c0392b;
  }
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}
.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
  color: #ffbbbc;
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.79.0">
    <title>ِAdmin Area Dashboard</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/starter-template/">

    

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    

    <!-- Favicons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#7952b3">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AdminStrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="pages.html">Pages</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="posts.html">Posts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="users.html">Users</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav  navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Welcome, Sameh</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
<!--
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
-->
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<header id="header">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-10">
                  <h1> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> Dashboard <small>Manage Your Site</small></h1>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</header>
    


    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer of your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434707/add-glyphicon-to-headings

Comment: is it semantically correct to use a small tag in a h1?  Small tags are for side notes or small print and I don't think a h1 would be classed as that - perhaps use a span and css instead (or just css on your h1 directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your codes. It seems like there is a problem on bootstrap version you're using. I removed both of your bootstrap links and added one. I also added Mansi's comment to make the icon be resizeable. You can check from below snippet

```css
body{
    background: #f4f4f4;
}

h1 span.glyphicon-cog{
    font-size: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: 5px;
}

.navbar-nav{
    min-height: 33px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}
.navbar .navbar-text {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar .navbar-text a {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}
.navbar .navbar-text a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-text a:focus {
  color: #ffbbbc; 
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:not(.disabled):hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:not(.disabled):focus {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  border-color: #c0392b;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
  color: #ffbbbc;
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-divider {
  border-top-color: #c0392b;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link:focus {
  color: #ffbbbc;
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler {
  border-color: #c0392b;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler:hover,
.navbar .navbar-toggler:focus {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse,
.navbar .navbar-form {
  border-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar .navbar-link {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}

.main-color-bg{
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  border-color: #c0392b;
  color:#ffffff;
}














@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #ffbbbc;
    background-color: #c0392b;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #ffbbbc;
    background-color: #c0392b;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #ffbbbc;
    background-color: #c0392b;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #ffbbbc;
    background-color: #c0392b;
  }
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}
.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
  color: #ffbbbc;
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.79.0">
    <title>ِAdmin Area Dashboard</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/starter-template/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    

    <!-- Favicons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#7952b3">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AdminStrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="pages.html">Pages</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="posts.html">Posts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="users.html">Users</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav  navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Welcome, Sameh</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
<!--
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
-->
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<header id="header">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-10">
                  <h1> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> Dashboard <small>Manage Your Site</small></h1>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</header>
    


    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

      
  </body>
</html>
```